# I can't open an application with Wine

Tags: wine

I am using Ubuntu, and when I run an application with Wine, I get an error like this.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000014 in 32-bit code (0x0042f774).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:0042f774 ESP:01dcf838 EBP:01dcf89c EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:01dcf858 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x01dcf838:  10012c9f 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x01dcf848:  00000000 10012da9 00000000 00000001
0x01dcf858:  004268ac 00200000 00000020 10020e08
0x01dcf868:  00200000 00200000 00000000 100214b2
0x01dcf878:  00000001 1001311f 00000001 688c97b0
0x01dcf888:  00000000 00000000 0044c320 10034350
Backtrace:
=>0 0x0042f774 in cod2sp (+0x2f774) (0x01dcf89c)
  1 0x10013307 in gfx_d3d_x86_s (+0x13307) (0x68915330)
  2 0x90906895 (0x912425ff)
0x0042f774 cod2sp+0x2f774: movl 0x14(%eax),%ecx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (64 modules)
PE  00370000-003d2000   Deferred        msacm32
PE  00400000-01cc3a46   Export          cod2sp
PE  020d0000-02548000   Deferred        ole32
PE  02550000-02763000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  02770000-028ce000   Deferred        d3d9
PE  028d0000-03c65000   Deferred        wined3d
PE  047f0000-04874000   Deferred        winex11
PE  10000000-10763000   Export          gfx_d3d_x86_s
PE  21100000-21164000   Deferred        mss32
PE  643c0000-64449000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  64a80000-64ad8000   Deferred        win32u
PE  65680000-658fc000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  66080000-66179000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  66640000-6665a000   Deferred        version
PE  667c0000-66805000   Deferred        shcore
PE  67500000-67553000   Deferred        imm32
PE  684c0000-6860d000   Deferred        combase
PE  68880000-68d6a000   Deferred        user32
PE  69840000-6993b000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  69ec0000-6a11f000   Deferred        ddraw
PE  6aac0000-6ad9c000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  6aec0000-6b06f000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  6bbc0000-6bc57000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6da80000-6dc9f000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  6f240000-6f3bc000   Deferred        winmm
PE  70d80000-70e20000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  71400000-720af000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7a800000-7acc1000   Deferred        opengl32
PE  7b000000-7b52c000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b759000   Deferred        kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bebc000   Deferred        ntdll
ELF 7d000000-7d005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e038000-7e040000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7e040000-7e04d000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7e04d000-7e062000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7e062000-7e067000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e067000-7e076000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e076000-7e084000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e084000-7e08c000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e08c000-7e091000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e091000-7e0a4000   Deferred        libmd.so.0
ELF 7e0a4000-7e0ba000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7e0ba000-7e0c2000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e0c2000-7e0c8000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e0c8000-7e0f6000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e0f6000-7e248000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e248000-7e25f000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e274000-7e2ff000   Deferred        winex11.so
ELF 7e2ff000-7e3a1000   Deferred        opengl32.so
ELF 7e550000-7e57c000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e57c000-7e5d0000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e5d0000-7e60d000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7e60d000-7e6e1000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e6e1000-7e7eb000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7ea8c000-7ec00000   Deferred        win32u.so
ELF 7ee02000-7ee25000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
ELF 7ee25000-7ee33000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
ELF 7ee33000-7ee46000   Deferred        libbz2.so.1.0
ELF 7ee46000-7ee63000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ee66000-7ee6c000   Deferred        ws2_32.so
ELF 7ee78000-7f000000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7c00000-f7e39000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7e94000-f7f42000   Deferred        ntdll.so
ELF f7f44000-f7f79000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000020 start.exe
    00000024    0     
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0     
    00000040    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000004c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    0000005c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000074    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000088    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000b8    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000d0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000e8    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0     
    00000054    0     
    00000058    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000060    0     
    00000064    0     
    00000068    0     
    000000dc    0     
0000006c winedevice.exe
    00000070    0     
    00000078    0     
    00000084    0     wine_sechost_service
    0000008c    0     
    00000090    0     
    00000094    0     
    00000098    0     
    000000a0    0     
0000007c explorer.exe
    00000080    0     
    000000a4    0     
    000000a8    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000b0 plugplay.exe
    000000b4    0     
    000000bc    0     
    000000c0    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000c4    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000c8 svchost.exe
    000000cc    0     
    000000d4    0     
    000000d8    0     wine_sechost_service
000000e0 rpcss.exe
    000000e4    0     
    000000ec    0     
    000000f0    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000f4    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000f8    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000fc    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000104 conhost.exe
    00000108    0     
0000010c winecfg.exe
    00000110    0     
00000114 winecfg.exe
    00000118    0     
0000011c (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Activision\Call Of Duty 2 Frontline\CoD2SP.exe
    00000120    0 <== 
    00000124    0     
    00000138    0     
00000130 conhost.exe
    00000134    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-8.0.1
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 6.5.0-17-generic
```

Comment: Might I be so presumptuous as to ask what the application is?

Comment: I think its COD2:
0000011c (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Activision\Call Of Duty 2 Frontline\CoD2SP.exe

Comment: BTW: Windows 10 is the wrong wine-prefix... You should use "winxp" for COD2 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First:

> when I run an application with Wine

There is no problem to say: "I want to play Call of Duty 2"

Windows 10 is the wrong Windows-Version. use `winecfg`:

There are two ways you can use winecfg to change settings. You can change settings for all applications ("Default Settings") or you can change settings for a specific application (which overrides the default settings). When you start winecfg, the Applications tab is shown with "Default Settings" selected. With "Default Settings" selected, changes made affect all applications.

To change settings only for a specific application:

In the Application tab, click the "Add application..." button.
Browse to and highlight the application then click the "Open" button.
With your application's filename still highlighted in the Application tab, changes only (i.e. in other tabs) affect that specific application.

Tip: When editing per application settings, the application name appears in the winecfg title bar.

Change the Windows Version to XP.

You can use https://appdb.winehq.org for hints of configuration or compatibility for your programs.

Maybe you should have a look at `playonlinux`. It will preconfigure wine (config and version) for your applications.